# foreign key mismatch on delete command for unrelated record

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, mismatch

I have the following 5 tables defined with a few records inserted into the 1st 4.  This is using sqlite 3.7.1.7 with foreign key constaint enabled.

```
create table if not exists subject (id varchar(50) primary key,desc varchar(100));
insert into subject (id,desc) values ("subject1","test subject");

create table if not exists subjectlevel (id_subject_id varchar(50) references subject(id) on delete cascade, id integer not null, desc varchar(100) not null, questmcmaxselections integer not null, primary key (id_subject_id,id));

insert into subjectlevel (id_subject_id,id,desc,questmcmaxselections) values ("subject1",1,"test subject1 level 1",4);

insert into subjectlevel (id_subject_id,id,desc,questmcmaxselections) values ("subject1",2,"test subject1 level 2",4);

create table if not exists questmc (id integer primary key, text varchar(300) not null, includeallanswers int not null, subject_id varchar(50), subjectlevel_id integer, foreign key (subject_id, subjectlevel_id) references subjectlevel (id_subject_id,id) on delete cascade); 

insert into questmc (text,includeallanswers,subject_id,subjectlevel_id) values ("this is a _ question", 1, "subject1",1);

create table if not exists questmcselection (id integer primary key, text varchar(100) not null, subject_id varchar(50), subjectlevel_id integer, foreign key (subject_id, subjectlevel_id) references subjectlevel (id_subject_id,id) on delete cascade);

insert into questmcselection (text,subject_id,subjectlevel_id) values ("this is a solution","subject1",1);

create table if not exists questmc_questmcselection(id integer primary key, answer integer not null, questmc_id integer, questmcselection_id integer, subject_id varchar(50), subjectlevel_id integer, foreign key (questmc_id) references questmc(id) on delete cascade, foreign key (questmcselection_id) references questmcselection (id) on delete cascade, foreign key (subject_id,subjectlevel_id) references questmc (subject_id,subjectlevel_id) on delete cascade, foreign key (subject_id,subjectlevel_id) references questmcselection (subject_id,subjectlevel_id));
```

if i attempt to delete the second record in the subjectlevel table, i get a foreign key mismatch error as long as table questmc_questmcselection is defined.

```
sqlite> delete from subjectlevel where id=2;
Error: foreign key mismatch - "questmc_questmcselection" referencing "questmcselection"
```

questmc, questmcselection, and questmc_questmcselection have no related existing records that should prevent this deletion.  Any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: It appears to not like the last 2 foreign keys defined on questmc_questmcselection table.  I removed the last one and then the second to last one (both of the (subject_id,subjectlevel_id) keys),  So this leads to the question, "does sqlite 3.7.1.7 support multiple foreign key links to the same table?

Comment: Maybe I should ask a bigger picture question.  I have a multiple choice (mc) question table and a selection table holding options that can be reused across questions. I need an n:n link between them.  However, both question and selection records have a subject and subjectlevel defined.  I need to insure n:n linking only allows linking of identical types.  How can I do that at the db level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with this particular `subjectlevel` record.

Your problem is that your tables lack [the required indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes).
This was not reported earlier because that `DELETE` statement was the first command that required SQLite to check the consistency of the database schema.

Comment: I am totally new to SQLite and somewhat new to SQL.  What indexes are needed to make this work?

Comment: I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible at the db level.  table A has an id and a type field.  table B has an id and a type field.  In both cases id is the primary key and type has values that come form the same value set.  table C provides an n:n link between A&B. However, I only want a link if records A&B have the same type.

Comment: Got it with help from CL.

Tables A and B should include id and type in their key. This is the unique indexes that CL was referring to. Table C should include 3 fields (aid, bid, type) and 2 fkey constraints as follows. 
foreign key (aid,type) reference A (id,type), foreign key (bid,type) reference B (id,type)

This allows you to link 2 records from A and B into table C only if they share the same type value.

Thanks for you help CL.

Answer (score 3):

Based on CL's answer -

```
sqlite> create table parent(a);
sqlite> create table child(a, FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES parent(a));
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> insert into parent values(3);
sqlite> insert into child values (3);
Error: foreign key mismatch - "child" referencing "parent"
sqlite> create unique index p_a on parent(a);
sqlite> insert into child values (3);
sqlite> _
```

From the documentation:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key
>   of the parent table. If [not], then the parent key columns must be
>   collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index [which uses]
>   the collation sequences ... in the CREATE TABLE
>   statement for the parent table.

i.e. the alternative is:

```
sqlite> create table parent(a, b, UNIQUE (a, b));
sqlite> create table child (x, y, FOREIGN KEY (x, y) REFERENCES parent(a, b));
```

(this also highlights multi-column foreign keys; they work with indexes too...)