# SqlLite - Foreign Key with Cascade Delete in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to use a foreign key on a child table and receiving an error when I delete a row off the parent.  This is my understanding of the delete with Cascade.
[Delete with Cascade](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/soreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

> A foreign key with cascade delete means that if a record in the parent
> table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table
> will automatically be deleted. This is called a cascade delete in
> SQLite.
>
> A foreign key with a cascade delete can only be defined in a CREATE
> TABLE statement.
>
> TIP: You can not add a foreign key with casade delete to a table using
> ALTER TABLE because SQLite does not support ADD CONSTRAINT in the
> ALTER TABLE statement. However, we will show you a workaround later in
> this tutorial that will allow you to add a foreign key with cascade
> delete to an existing table.

Herre are is the DDL for my parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE Astro_Target_Imaged (
    ATI_TargetName                TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ATI_Telescope                 TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ATI_FocalLength               TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ATI_SITELONG                  TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ATI_SITELAT                   TEXT     NOT NULL,
    ATI_ICAMERA                   TEXT,
    ATI_ROTNAME                   TEXT,
    ATI_ROTATOR                   TEXT,
    ATI_FWHEEL                    TEXT,
    ATI_FOCNAME                   TEXT,
    ATI_GCAMERA                   TEXT,
    ATI_GSCOPE,
    ATI_Location_Name             TEXT,
    ATI_DataFolder_Location       TEXT,
    ATI_Posted_FinalProcessed_URL TEXT,
    ATI_Bortle                    TEXT (1),
    ATI_Archived                  TEXT (1) DEFAULT N,
    ATI_ArchiveFolderLocation     TEXT,
    ATI_DateAdded                 TEXT,
    ATI_DateLastUpdated           TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        ATI_TargetName,
        ATI_Telescope,
        ATI_FocalLength,
        ATI_SITELONG,
        ATI_SITELAT
    )
);
```

And here is the child table that I applied the Cascade and foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE Astro_Target_Imaged_Date (
    ATI_TargetName          TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_TargetName) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ATI_Telescope           TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_Telescope) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ATI_FocalLength         TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_FocalLength) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ATID_CCYYMMDD           TEXT        NOT NULL,
    ATI_SITELONG            TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_SITELONG) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ATI_SITELAT             TEXT        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_SITELAT) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    TZ_UTC_Offset           INTEGER (2),
    MI_Illumination_Percent TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        ATI_TargetName,
        ATI_Telescope,
        ATI_FocalLength,
        ATID_CCYYMMDD,
        ATI_SITELONG,
        ATI_SITELAT
    )
);
```

The error message:

> [10:45:08] Error while deleting row from table Astro_Target_Imaged:
> foreign key mismatch - "Astro_Target_Imaged_Date" referencing
> "Astro_Target_Imaged"

I don't see the mismatch on names, but I may be looking right past it.

Comment: I think I found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013339/foreign-key-mismatch-on-delete-command-for-unrelated-record   I know how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment yes if applied that should fix the issue.

That is the parent specified in the foreign key MUST be able to refer to a unique row (of the parent table), if it exists, not potentially multiple  rows.

As such a UNQIUE index per FKEY definition MUST exist (implicitly if the primary key) or explicitly via a UNIQUE index.

In your case 5 such indexes would be required but NONE of them exist. However you probably want to reflect the uniqueness of the parent. That is to have a composite Foreign Key definition.

A composite  Foreign Key definition cannot be defined at the column level, so has to be defined at the table level as a constraint, the syntax being:-

[image] *https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html*

It would appear that you want:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Astro_Target_Imaged_Date (
    ATI_TargetName          TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        -- REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_TargetName) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ,
    ATI_Telescope           TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        -- REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_Telescope) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ,
    ATI_FocalLength         TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        -- REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_FocalLength) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ,
    ATID_CCYYMMDD           TEXT        NOT NULL,
    ATI_SITELONG            TEXT        NOT NULL
                                        -- REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_SITELONG) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ,
    ATI_SITELAT             TEXT        -- REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_SITELAT) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                        ,
    
    TZ_UTC_Offset           INTEGER (2),
    MI_Illumination_Percent TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        ATI_TargetName,
        ATI_Telescope,
        ATI_FocalLength,
        ATID_CCYYMMDD,
        ATI_SITELONG,
        ATI_SITELAT
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (ATI_TargetName,ATI_Telescope,ATI_FocalLength,ATI_SITELONG,ATI_SITELAT)
        REFERENCES Astro_Target_Imaged (ATI_TargetName,ATI_Telescope,ATI_FocalLength,ATI_SITELONG,ATI_SITELAT)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

- **note** commented out the original column level FKEY definitions
- **note** added ON UPDATE for demo:-

Using your code, amended as above and then:-

```
INSERT INTO Astro_Target_Imaged
    VALUES ('T1','TEL1','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T2','TEL1','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T3','TEL1','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T4','TEL1','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T5','TEL2','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T6','TEL2','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
    ,('T7','TEL2','F1','SLON1','SLAT200','CAM1','RNAME1','ROR1','W1','FNAME1','GCAM1','GSCOPE1','LOC1','DLOC1','URL1','BORTLE1','ARCY','ARCF1','2024-01-01','2024-01-01')
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Astro_Target_Imaged_Date
    VALUES ('T1','TEL1','F1','2024-01-01','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T1','TEL1','F1','2024-01-02','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T1','TEL1','F1','2024-01-03','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T2','TEL1','F1','2024-01-03','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T2','TEL1','F1','2024-01-04','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T3','TEL1','F1','2024-01-01','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T3','TEL1','F1','2024-01-02','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T3','TEL1','F1','2024-01-03','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T5','TEL2','F1','2024-01-01','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
    ,('T5','TEL2','F1','2024-01-02','SLON1','SLAT200',10,50)
;
;
SELECT a.ati_targetname, a.ati_telescope,b.atid_ccyymmdd,*  FROM astro_target_imaged AS a JOIN astro_target_imaged_date AS b 
    ON a.ati_targetname = b.ati_targetname
    AND a.ati_telescope = b.ati_telescope
    AND a.ati_focallength = b.ati_focallength
    AND a.ati_sitelong = b.ati_sitelong
    AND a.ati_sitelat = b.ati_sitelat
;
DELETE FROM astro_target_imaged WHERE ati_targetname = 'T1';
SELECT a.ati_targetname, a.ati_telescope,b.atid_ccyymmdd,*  FROM astro_target_imaged AS a JOIN astro_target_imaged_date AS b 
    ON a.ati_targetname = b.ati_targetname
    AND a.ati_telescope = b.ati_telescope
    AND a.ati_focallength = b.ati_focallength
    AND a.ati_sitelong = b.ati_sitelong
    AND a.ati_sitelat = b.ati_sitelat
;
SELECT * FROM astro_target_imaged_date;
UPDATE astro_target_imaged SET ati_targetname = 'UPDATED'||ati_targetname WHERE ati_targetname LIKE '%5';
SELECT a.ati_targetname, a.ati_telescope,b.atid_ccyymmdd,*  FROM astro_target_imaged AS a JOIN astro_target_imaged_date AS b 
    ON a.ati_targetname = b.ati_targetname
    AND a.ati_telescope = b.ati_telescope
    AND a.ati_focallength = b.ati_focallength
    AND a.ati_sitelong = b.ati_sitelong
    AND a.ati_sitelat = b.ati_sitelat
;
SELECT * FROM astro_target_imaged_date;
```

- note that the first 3 columns output are the significant columns for the demo hence `SELECT a.ati_targetname, a.ati_telescope,b.atid_ccyymmdd,* ....`

The results are:-

**The original SELECT**:-

[image]

- all permutations of the original data inserted

**The `SELECT` after deleting T1's from the parent**:-

[image]

**The ...._date table** (i.e. the result of the deletes being cascaded):-

[image]

- i.e. ALL 3 T1 permutations have have been deleted from the single T1 parent being deleted

**The SELECT after the update of the single T5 parent**:-

[image]

**and the ...._date table**:-

[image]

- i.e. the update has been cascaded

Comment: Thank you Mike.  As soon as I looked at your answer, it made total sense.  I don't know why I didn't see or think of that.  Again, thank you.

Comment: Thank you again.  I actually needed to carry what you showed me to 1 lower child segment.  This worked perfectaly.  I can't beleive I didn't think about doing it this way.